# List of tuples: how to unpack nested tuples?

Tags: python-3.x

**I have no idea what the title should be, so please feel free to modify it.**

I have a massive (millions) list of tuples which look like this:

```
    tuples = list(zip(grid, flattened_values, timestamps))
    list(tuples[85864725])
>>> [(1000, -34.25, 50.625), 4.4577124419932667e-10, datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 5, 0, 0)]
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
>>> [1000, -34.25, 50.625, 4.4577124419932667e-10, datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 5, 0, 0)]
```

The best thing I could come up with is:

```
(tuples[85864725][0][0],tuples[85864725][0][1],tuples[85864725][0][2],tuples[85864725][1])
```

What is the best way to achieve this? Given that there are millions of tuples, I need a solution which is as performant (in terms of speed) as possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're using any version >= python 3.5 you can do: `[*(1000, -34.25, 50.625), 4.4577124419932667e-10, ...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpack the tuples from `grid` with `*`:

```
tuples = [(*x, y, z) for (x, y, z) in zip(grid, flattened_values, timestamps)]
```